# Clone Drive Using Linux DD Command: Send IMG Over SSH Connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, clone, dd

I SSH to a VPN running Ubuntu Linux. To make backup copies of the hard drive, I use the following dd command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/rick/hdImage-20150704.img
```

It works, however, is there a way I can, instead of making the clone IMG on the same drive, send it to myself over my SSH connection so I can download it?

The reason I need a way to do something like this is because the main hard drive is getting filled up, and I don't have other drives or partitions on it to use. If I could just send the IMG to myself (as a download), it wouldn't waste more space on the main drive.

Comment: See [How to dd a remote disk using SSH on local machine and save to a local disk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-disk). . You could also use NFS if your other machine supports it.

Comment: You can also use `sshfs` to mount remote drive and then save image as you normal do.

Answer (score 1):

This will copy the entire drive into a file on the remote machine:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX | ssh user@destination_server_ip 'dd of=sdX.img'
```

source: https://blog.bravi.org/?p=259

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `of` of `dd` can be remote. However, you can send the resulting image right after `dd` completes and then remove it to free disk space with a command similar to this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/rick/hdImage-20150704.img && scp /home/rick/hdImage-20150704.img user@host:/remote/location/hdImage-20150704.img && rm /home/rick/hdImage-20150704.img
```

The `&&` operator waits for the preceding command to finish and if that was successful (exit code is 0), then the following command is executed.

So this way you can run 3 commands one after the other to 1) make image 2) copy it to remote location 3) remove locally.

Comment: I believe the OP is saying they don't have room on the local machine to hold the `img` file, and this solution doesn't avoid that problem.